# Add or remove element based on value in number field

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what i have tried so far.

```js
$("#add_row").change(function(){

    $(".box").append('test <br />');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="add_row" type="number">
 
 <div class="box"></div>
```

Now what i want to add or remove the fields based on the number in number field

Comment: It's much easier to hide/show than it is to append/remove. Also based on what number? You've not given the logic here - or even made any attempt yourself.

Comment: I think hide/show doesn't fit here,as user can type any digit value.

Comment: ... and do what? You've not explained what you're trying to actually do

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am wondering how can i append or remove div based on the value of the number field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have emptied the `box` before appending so no need to worry about decreased value

Note: You need to validate for minus input (Not sure about your requirement but it can be done in different way)

```js
$("#add_row").change(function(){
 var total = $(this).val();
 var oldLength = $(".box > span").length;
 var change = total - oldLength;
 if (change > 0) {
  for (i = 0; i < change; i++) {
   $(".box").append('<span >test <br /></span>');
  }
 }
 else {
  change = Math.abs(change)
  $( ".box > span" ).each(function( index ) {    
   $(this).remove();
   if (index == (change -1)) {
    return false;
   }
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="add_row" type="number">
 
 <div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: what if i don't want to null the box fields,because if we have 4 elements,it should increase or decreased the elements length not entirely empty all the values.

Comment: you may need to count the existing elements and increment / decrement accordingly

Comment: Ok,if you don't mind can  you please update your answer?

Comment: I have already fixed this,anyways thank you so much for your effort.
Please up vote my answer,some one has already down voted it for no reasons.

Answer (score 1):

A really basic implementation. However you may wish to introduce input sanitization including a maximum limit:

```
$("#add_row").change(function(){

    var total = $(this).val();
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
      $(".box").append('test <br />');
    }

});
```